# ComPtr<ID3D11Device> to IntPtr

Tags: c++, direct3d

I'm an absolute zero at C++. But I need to write a small c++ class for managing a d3ddevice.
My **C# code** is:

```
public class HCPPUtils
{ 
    [DllImport("HSpectrum\\Assets\\HCPPUtils.dll")]
    private static extern int Getd3Device(ICanvasResourceCreator resourceCreator);}
    HCPPUtils hcp = new HCPPUtils();
    var pnt =  hcp.HGetOrCreate(ResourceCreator);
    var d3dDevice = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.FromPointer<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device>(new System.IntPtr(pnt));
```

My **C++ code** is:

```
extern "C"
{
     __declspec(dllexport) int Getd3Device
    (Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::ICanvasResourceCreator^ canvasDevice)
    {
         ComPtr<ID3D11Device> m_device;
         __abi_ThrowIfFailed(Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::GetDXGIInterface(canvasDevice->Device,m_device.GetAddressOf()));
          return m_device???
    }
}
```

How can i return a IntPtr from C++ code; so, how can i get IntPtr from ComPtr < ID3D11Device >?

[edited]

What I'm doing is...
I have a win2d canvasandimatedcontrol in my c# project. I want to draw direct3d object in it using sharpdx. But I found out that I need to have the d3ddevice object from win2d canvas. And there isn't a c# method to get it.
So the only solution I can imagine is to build a simple c++ project to which I can pass the canvas control and get the d3ddevice. The only problem is how to pass back the d3d device to c#. Sharp DX seems to have just a method Device.FormIntPtr to create it. But I'm not able to pass back the intptr to the c# object.

I tried to implement what Rook wrote, but I cannot understand how it could be useful for my scenario. I mean it could be usueful, but I need to pass the IDirect3DDevice object from a c++ project anyway.

Comment: If my answer was inadequate, you could say so and it might get altered. If it was helpful, you should consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry for not replaying earlier, but I'm still looking for a way to do what I meant. Your answer wasn't inadequate. It was useful about reading a bit more about the argument...

Comment: @Rook Added info in the original post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you need to do is to read the docs for things like this: http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDevice_CreateFromDirect3D11Device.htm

`CanvasDevice` implements `ICanvasResourceCreator`, so you could return it directly once you've created it using the static factory method.

Be careful with the scope and lifetime of `m_device` here, because you don't want its refcount to be decremented when `Getd3Device` returns and the `ComPtr` goes out of scope. I'm assuming that it is actually part of a class that will look after its lifetime, but it bears repeating just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to access the unity3d device today. This is how I passed the pointer back into unity/managed code:

cpp:

```
/*
delegate to pass directx device/context back to managed code
see https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/communicating-c-with-c.89930/#post-586885
*/
typedef int(__stdcall *ANSWERCB)(ID3D11Device* ptr);
static ANSWERCB cb;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetDevice(ANSWERCB fp)
{
    cb = fp;
    if (cb)
    {
        return cb(s_CurrentAPI->GetDevice());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

cs:

```
[DllImport("RenderingPlugin")]
private static extern void GetDevice(Action<IntPtr> callback);
```

later I call:

```
GetDevice(devicePtr =>
{
    Debug.Log(devicePtr);
    if (devicePtr == IntPtr.Zero) return;
    device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device.FromPointer<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device>(devicePtr);

...
```

works fine in the editor as well as the built in the new 2017.1 beta version (as long as you copy the necessary 64bit system dlls to unitys plugin folder)